# pins to control screen rotation, which API for linux kernel<->userspace to choose?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I have lcd screen connected to arm cpu,
and there are two pins on this lcd screen to control
where is left,top corner on the screen (2 pins = 4 variants).

And I don't know which API to use to control left,top corner from userspace?

The most simple one just export this pins via gpio sysfs interface,
but I don't like this solution, because of user app should not know such details,
as gpio number connected to lcd panel.

The another solution modify fbdev video driver and add paramter to control "left,top corner", good enough, but there are disadvantages:
1)require std video driver of my arm cpu modification
2)user space application should use such not standard interface

may there is common way to expose such functionality to userspace in linux kernel?

At now I expose this pins via leds interface:
/sys/class/leds/lcd_dpsh

switch 1/0 is made via echo 255/0 > brightness

But don't like "leds" part of interface, and also "brightness"
But may be there is something like "switcher" sysfs class?

Comment: What is the model of your LCD? Is there any available drivers in kernel for this LCD? And how did you describe those two GPIO lines in your device tree file? Also, is there any available code in user-space applications to control this behavior (left-top corner of the screen)? If so -- you should provide exactly the same interface from kernel. If no -- maybe you shouldn't provide such an interface (from kernel to user-space) at all?

Comment: I used default omap3 framebuffer driver with panel-dpi "plugin". At now I describe them as " LEDs". No user space app, bul I am going to write it. Analog of this interface is framebuffer rotation mechanic, but with pins and lcd display help my variant is much faster. I look at android, to see how they do rotation, but looks like it all in user space.

Comment: Why do you need to use those two pins in the first place? I thought that screen rotation is done exclusively by software, without involving any LCD screen rotating capabilities. So maybe you just need to ignore those pins (hard wire them so your top-left corner is fixed), and then rotate screen by software? If it's not acceptable, and all you are worrying about is that your user-space application need to know GPIO number to control these lines -- just request those GPIOs in your LCD driver and expose them as fixed sysfs nodes. Would such a solution be acceptable for you?

Comment: My point is, all this stuff with those LCD pins seem to be a very non-common for me (I haven't managed to find any examples in device tree files for ARM boards in kernel). This makes me think that you may not needed to use those pins at all.

Comment: I would like to see datasheet for this LCD you are using. Is it free to download? If so, where I can find it?